# How do I find what's wrong with the certificate used for EAP-TLS?

Tags: openssl, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect Raspberry Pi to a EAP-TLS Wi-Fi access point. The connection fails:

```
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
OpenSSL: tls_read_pkcs12 - Failed to use PKCS#12 file error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
OpenSSL: tls_connection_private_key - Failed to load private key error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
TLS: Failed to load private key '/etc/ssl/private/demo.key'
TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.
```

When I search for “ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag,” all I can find is the suggestions that the certificate file is somehow damaged, and that I need to check that there are no leading or trailing spaces. The file seems fine, besides when I run `openssl rsa -check -noout -in /etc/ssl/private/demo.key`, it prompts for the pass phrase, and when I enter one, it prints: “RSA key ok.”

I also double-checked the password stored in `private_key_passwd` in `wpa_supplicant.conf` and it looks correct.

How do I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl rsa` expects a PEM encoded RSA key by default, but the error message suggests the `wpa_supplicant` is assuming that the key file is PKCS#12 encoded.

After reading the description of the `private_key` configuration item of `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `/usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf`, it seems the behavior is as follows:

- if your client certificate and the corresponding private key are in PEM format, you should specify the filenames of both of them, using `client_cert` and `private_key` configuration items, respectively.
- if your client certificate and private key are in a single PKCS#12 file (suffix typically .pfx or .p12, not directly readable with `openssl rsa`), then you should only specify the filename with the `private_key` configuration item, and not use the `client_cert` configuration item at all. In other words, if `client_cert` is not specified and `private_key` is a plain filename, `wpa_supplicant` will expect a PKCS#12 format.
- if the `client_cert` configuration item does not exist and the `private_key` configuration item contains one of several possible URI-style formats, these will be interpreted as references to PKCS#11 tokens (smart cards) or to certificates stored in Windows certificate store, if applicable.

It looks like you've failed to specify `client_cert` in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.