# How do I generate the certificates for EAP-TLS Wi-Fi?

Tags: openssl, wpa-supplicant, 802.1x

I want to connect a Linux machine to WPA2 Enterprise Wi-Fi (that I manage). The certificates I created with OpenSSL work well with Android and iOS devices, but I can't figure out what types of certificates are expected by wpa_supplicant.

Basically, I have a ca.pem, and, for a given device, the following files are being generated:

- demo.crt
- demo.csr
- demo.key
- demo.p12

[It looks like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581236/11229) wpa_supplicant can work with either a file containing both the public and the private certificate, as well as two files. Originally, I was using two files:

- demo.key
- demo.pem, created by running `openssl pkcs12 -in demo.p12 -out demo.pem -clcerts`.

`wpa_supplicant.conf` was configured like this:

```
network={
    ssid="HelloWorld"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=TLS
    identity="demo@example.com"
    ca_cert="/etc/ssl/private/ca.pem"
    client_cert="/etc/ssl/private/demo.pem"
    private_key="/etc/ssl/private/demo.key"
    private_key_passwd=...
}
```

The authentication fails with the following error:

> OpenSSL: tls_read_pkcs12 - Failed to use PKCS#12 file error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

If I remove `client_cert` and use only `private_key`, pointing to the .pem file, the error is still the same.

If I point it to .p12, the error is:

> OpenSSL: tls_connection_private_key - Failed to load private key error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

Debian's documentation [tells that](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/wpasupplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.en.html#CERTIFICATES) the PEM should be created from a .pfx. When I do that:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out demo.pfx -inkey demo.key -in demo.crt -certfile ca.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in demo.pfx -out demo.pem -clcerts
```

the original error is back:

> OpenSSL: tls_read_pkcs12 - Failed to use PKCS#12 file error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

How exactly should I generate the certificates for wpa_supplicant?

Comment: If you are creating your certificates on the windows side, either this is not the right group to ask or the question is not correctly framed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Windows side? The certificates are generated on a Linux machine. Although I'm not sure how this is relevant: I suppose that OpenSSL generates the same certificates independently of the operating system.

Comment: Ah. Debian docs does not say you need .pfx, hence the confusion. It says it needs PEM, no matter what format  it is received. For EAP-TTLS, client certificates are not mandatory. (and Windows use their own tools)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I see. Sorry, my question is indeed not easily readable, but I can't figure out how can I make it more readable without removing necessary details. Essentially, the question itself is in the title. The details are here to avoid answers which barely tell what I already know/have tried, such as “Simply use .p12 and it will work”—no, it won't.

Comment: Are you authenticating users via certificate or is just the server certificate? Or both? Are Windows or mobile clients authenticating?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: each *device* (rather than a user) has its own certificate (`demo.pem` in my question). Among the clients, there are two Android devices and an iOS device; all three use their own client certificates and have no issues authenticating. The RADIUS server has, obviously, its own certificate.

Comment: in my experience iOS devices are much more finicky with web/RADIUS certificates than Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, it should be `eap=TTLS`

As in:

```
network={
ssid="HelloWorld"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
eap=TTLS
identity="demo@example.com"
ca_cert="/etc/ssl/private/ca.pem"
client_cert="/etc/ssl/private/demo.pem"
private_key="/etc/ssl/private/demo.key"
private_key_passwd=...
}
```

Also, depending on the configuration, you might need `anonymous_identity` and `phase2`.

Supposing it is EAP-TTLS-MSChapv2:

```
network={
ssid="HelloWorld"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
eap=TTLS
identity="demo@example.com"
ca_cert="/etc/ssl/private/ca.pem"
client_cert="/etc/ssl/private/demo.pem"
private_key="/etc/ssl/private/demo.key"
private_key_passwd=...
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Comment: The question was about EAP-TLS, but the answer is for EAP-TTLS-MSCHAPv2. As long as this is your private AP you could just change the authentication protocol. In the general case you cannot.